# if an object does not have the value - do not display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to do something like that. When my employee does not have a particular value that it is not displayed. I tried to do it like this:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (!item.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Przewodnik.Pracownik.Osoba.Imie)
                </td> 
                    (...)
```

But it give me a `.NullReferenceException`.

```
if(item.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia != null){...}
```

I tried this as well, but also give error.

Comment: Debug your code! Possibly `Przewodnik` is `null`

Comment: those who down vote should leave a comment explaining why so the question poster can improve whatever the down vote is meant to point out.  Constructive feedback will help build somebody up which I believe is what SO strives for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item != null && item.Przewodnik != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia)) { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Przewodnik.Pracownik.Osoba.Imie)
                </td> 
                    (...)
```

Comment: While Ala's solution works, you should also look for the root cause of null ref which may point you to issues upstream that feeds data to your UI.

Comment: certainly I do, thanks